# Find equations of circle

Tags: linear-algebra

I am preparing for an exam and have this problem, which I don't know how to solve:

Find equations of circles, that touch the line $p: 7x-y-5=0$ in $[1,2]$ and touch line $q: x+y+13=0$

Comment: By "touch the line in $[1,2]$" do you mean "is tangent to the line at $[1,2]$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, excuse my english.

Comment: Do you know how to find the distance from a point to a line?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes.

Comment: This is a bit tricky because the conditions do not define a unique circle, there are infinitely many such circles.  So your answer will have to depend on at least on parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal vectors of the lines are
$$
\vec n_p=\begin{pmatrix}7\\-1\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\vec n_q=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
It is easy to show that $|\vec n_p|=|5\vec n_q|$ so a normal vector to one of the bisecting lines will be
$$
\vec n_p+5\vec n_q=\begin{pmatrix}12\\4\end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
which can be reduced by a factor $4$. The lines $p,q$ [intersect at](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7x-y-5%3D0%2Cx%2By%2B13%3D0) $(-1,-12)$ so the equations for the bisecting lines will be
$$
\begin{align}
\ell_1&:3(x+1)+(y+12)=0\\
\ell_2&:-(x+1)+3(y+12)=0
\end{align}
$$
The line $\omega$ through $(1,2)$ perpendicular to $p$ passes through the center of the circles in question. This line has equation
$$
\omega:(x-1)+7(y-2)=0
$$
The lines $\ell_1,\omega$ [intersect at](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%28x%2B1%29%2B%28y%2B12%29%3D0%2C%28x-1%29%2B7%28y-2%29%3D0) $(-6,3)$, whereas $\ell_2,\omega$ [intersect at](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28x%2B1%29%2B3%28y%2B12%29%3D0%2C%28x-1%29%2B7%28y-2%29%3D0) $(29,-2)$. So the two candidate circles are:

1. Centered at $(-6,3)$ running through $(1,2)$

or

2. Centered at $(29,-2)$ running through $(1,2)$

The rest is up to you :)

---

Diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the center of the circle must be on one of the two lines that bisects the angles between your given lines.  That means that the distance from the center to each line is the same.

Comment: Can you give me one more hint how to get the equation of the line that bisects the angles?

Comment: you can take the arctangent of the slopes of the two lines to get the angles they make with the horizontal, then take the angle that is halfway in between, and take the tangent of that to get the slope.

Comment: Thanks for help, but still have no clue :-/

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  You have two crossing lines-have you found the point of intersection?  Can you see why the center of the circle has to be on one of the bisectors-that is a theorem of Euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Choose proper vertex location to contain the circle centered on bisectors. Use  slope - normal form of straight line:

$ p = \dfrac{a x + by + c }{ \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}} = \pm \dfrac{A x + B y + C }{ \sqrt {A^2 + B^2}} $

Answer (score 0):

Here an analitic approach.

You search circles with equation $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$.

If this circle is tangent to the straight line $7x-y-5=0$ then the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0\\
7x-y-5=0
\end{cases}
$$
has discriminant $\Delta_1(a,b,c)=0$
For the other straight line you have an analogous system with $\Delta_2(a,b,c)=0$.

Since you want that the circle be tangent to the two lines, you find:

$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta_1(a,b,c)=0\\
\Delta_2(a,b,c)=0
\end{cases}
$$
This is a system with two equations and three unknowns and solving it you find a  family of circle depending by one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1184191
$L_0:7x-y-5=0$
$L_1:x+y+13=0$
$P_0(1\mid 2)$, a point in $L_0$
$P_1({-1}\mid{-12})$, intersection of $L_0$ and $L_1$
$L_2:x+7y-15=0$, perpendicular to $L_0$ through $P_0$

$(x-15+7t)^2+(y-t)^2=(14-7t)^2+(t-2)^2$, family of circles tangent to $L_0$ at $P_0$, parametrized by $t$
The locus of their centers is $L_2$.
Consider the pair of lines $L_0$ and $L_1$. They form two angles. Bisect the two angles. Their two intersections with $L_2$ correspond to two values of $t$ (which can be arrived at algebraically) and define the two required circles with centers $(25-7t\mid t)$ and radii $\sqrt{(14-7t)^2+(t-2)^2}$.